# UIPopover is repositioned but in the wrong place

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I have this code to reposition my popover:

```
- (void)repositionPopOver {

    if (self.targetButton) {

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.targetButton.frame
                                                inView:self.view
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                              animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    // Reposition the Popover after rotation
    [self repositionPopOver];
}
```

So now when I rotate the device it does re-position my popover but in the wrong spot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [minus.com](http://i.minus.com/jbxYSIHSJhV8yC.png))</sub>

Please note that the red rectangle is the `targetButton`

Comment: Check that didRotate is actually getting called.  In repositionPopOver, check that targetButton and popoverController are not nil.

Comment: Be careful about the "inView" parameter you are passing. Does your button exist in self.view?

Answer (score 0):

while rotation ,You can try dismissing popOver first and then recreate it and show it based on the orientation.
    {
     if([YourPopUpViewControllerOBject].isPopOverVisible)
     {
         [[YourPopUpViewControllerOBject] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
     }
     //Code to show PopOver based on orientation
   }